# How to deal with small statistics in plotting a "good" and "representative" plot for a limited number of measurements in simulation runs?

Tags: data-visualization, small-sample

In a cosmological simulation, we are calculating a physical quantity at different times from 3 different viewing angles; that is at any particular snapshot or epoch, we have three output numbers for the physical quantity. From each run, we have one time array including its error (called **x** and **xerr**) and one physical quantity array including its error (called **y** and **yerr**). In order to plot **x** vs. **y**, I am using `matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar(x, y, xerr, yerr)` function in Python3 in which **y** is set to the *RMS* value of the three output numbers corresponding to each **x** and **yerr** is set to the *STD value* for the limited number of 3 trials. This is the way my **x** and **y** arrays have been produced. Here you can find my original question that I initially posted in a wrong page where you can see my python script. ([Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954345/how-does-error-propagation-work-for-error-bars-that-are-in-numpy-array-format-fo?noredirect=1#comment69173078_40954345))

Given the complexity and expense of the simulations, we have only 5 runs corresponding to 5 distinct astrophysical environments having the same characteristic. This means that I can produce the same **x** vs. **y** plot for each of the 5 distinct runs in which *RMS* values are connected via straight lines and each data point has a vertical "error bar" associated with it. Since we only had 3 trials for each epoch, we cannot really establish a rigorous Poisson statistics in order to come up with a True Standard Deviation for each *RMS* value of **y**. Regardless of the fact that we are able to produce 5 plots, we don't know the number of STDs in the magnitude of the error bar calculated with such limited number of trials.

Now, given this limitation, I would like to have a "good" single representative "average" plot which can be safely assumed to be typical for the five distinct simulation runs.

The way I have come up with is to use matplotlib module of Python3 to produce an "average" plot basically by averaging the *RMS* values of **y** at each **x** simply averaging 5 *RMS* values at any **x** common to all runs; however I don't know how to deal with the error bars corresponding to **y** values. I think the best way is to draw the joining lines as having a finite width or a sort of *confidence interval* but I do not know how to combine 5 error arrays which are not true STDs by any means.

Here are the mentioned plots:

[image: 5 runs]

[image: RMS]

Comment: So, why we dont have any sample of your plots, for better understanding why the simple `rms`, `max`, `stdev` among others, do not solve your problem?

Comment: Plots are up now. I don't have problem with central values represented as dots but with the magnitude of the resultant error bar in the second "average" plot.

Comment: Indeed, the RMS representative failed to expose any proper pattern on here. Beside the fact that we only have five samples. In other words, your procedure is not getting any significative tendency. At some ranges, the values even go down!.... Perhaps you should clarify and change your methodology...........

Comment: With such a low number of observations, you might be able to show `min`, `max` and `mean` or `median`. All other summary statistics will be practically useless because of extreme volatility.